# Which side of Europa is which?

Tags: jupiter, europa, mapping, coordinates, tidal-locking

I understand that Europa is tidally locked* to Jupiter, so there's a Jovianmost longitude on one side and an anti-Jovian longitude on the other.

What I can't figure out is which side is which.  Looking at [a map of Europa](http://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Page/EUROPA/target), is Dyfed Regio (for example) right near the Jovian longitude or the anti-Jovian longitude?

[image: map of europa]

---

*I've read some articles that say Europa might precess more than we previously expected.  For this question, that doesn't matter.  I'm just asking about its current orientation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard for any tidally locked body, of which Europa is a member, is to have the 0 longitude be the point at the center of the planet-facing side. That being the case, the middle of the map should be the portion facing Jupiter, the edges the part that never faces Jupiter. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude) for the referenced quote below:

> Tidally-locked bodies have a natural reference longitude passing through the point nearest to their parent body: 0° the center of the primary-facing hemisphere, 90° the center of the leading hemisphere, 180° the center of the anti-primary hemisphere, and 270° the center of the trailing hemisphere.

That being said, the source image for your map is found at the [USGS website](http://pubs.usgs.gov/imap/i2757/). The far right side is 0 degrees longitude, the far left 360, of the image shown below:

[image]

The darker region, which is the central piece for your image, is centered around 250 degrees longitude. In fact, looking at the [database of features on Europa](http://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/SearchResults?target=EUROPA), we find out that [Dyfed Regio](http://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Feature/14293;jsessionid=0EDE9FA3CBD068B6DBD5D1D07EA85DA1) is 10 lat, 250 longitude.

Comment: So that means Dyfed Regio is in the middle of the anti-Jovian hemisphere?  (I just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.)

Comment: @Joe: Added a bunch more to my answer, it's much better now.

Comment: So I have heard that anyone can just call up the USGS and order one of their maps for free, can anyone verify?  Because I would really like a copy of that map.

Comment: Never heard of that.  You can buy 'em from their store for $9, which isn't bad.

Comment: Does the dark spot align with the velocity vector?

Answer (score 3):

I find the accepted answer unclear, so I'll try:

The two maps in discussion use coordinate systems based on the convention that 0 longitude is the point directly facing Jupiter, but they have chosen to put that point on the far right-hand edge of the map.

Dyfed Regio is on Europa's Trailing and Anti-Jovian hemispheres (not the Sub-Jovian).

Note that the maps posted by @PearsonArtPhoto and that posted by @Joe have different labels (e.g. the USGS one doesn't have regia) but do use the same coordinate system. Here's a figure from https://doi.org/10.1016/j.icarus.2018.04.016 which also uses the same coordinate system and could be helpful:

[image]